# d3js Box and Whisker plot: add a single circle to plot given a point in the distribution

Tags: javascript, d3.js

How can I add a single circle to plot given a point in the distribution?

I'm looking to modify [this popular d3js example](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4061502) of a box-and-whisker plot.  My goal is to **tag a single data point** on a given plot.  When charting a distribution, it would be nice to illustrate where a given element falls on that distribution!

Visually, my current attempt has yielded something like this: 
[image: boxAndWhiskerExample]

But this is really ghetto.  The red `marker` is drawn by using an `axis`, appending a separate `g` element and attempting to mimic the `y` scale. Code [via GitHub](https://github.com/DeBraid/puck/blob/new-box-plot/app/skater-mode/skater-mode.directive.js#L109)

```
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .tickSubdivide(1)
    .tickSize(0, 6, 0)
    .ticks(1)
    .tickValues([skater_val])
    .tickFormat(function (d, i) {
        // add the marker as axis label  
        return skater_val + "  >";  
    })
    .orient("right");

 // draw y axis
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + -10 + "," + 0 + ")")
    .call(yAxis);
```

This approach is inconsistent, and doesn't look very good.

Ideally I'd like to modify [d3.box()](https://github.com/DeBraid/puck/blob/new-box-plot/app/skater-mode/box.js) and include something like `outliers` described below.

Pick a data point, mark it on the plot.  Easy right? ...

### Original Attempt:

I'd like to arbitrarily select any data point and draw a circle where it appear on a d3js boxplot from [this popular example](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4061502).

So far I have tried to adapt the code for `outliers`, which do something very similar to what I'd like to achieve: render a circle on the plot for a given data point (has unique `name`).

The code from the example is as follows: how range / domain / scale is being created?

```
  // Compute whiskers. Must return exactly 2 elements, or null.
  var whiskerIndices = whiskers && whiskers.call(this, d, i),
      whiskerData = whiskerIndices && whiskerIndices.map(function(i) { return d[i]; });

  // Compute outliers. If no whiskers are specified, all data are "outliers".
  // We compute the outliers as indices, so that we can join across transitions!
  var outlierIndices = whiskerIndices
      ? d3.range(0, whiskerIndices[0]).concat(d3.range(whiskerIndices[1] + 1, n))
      : d3.range(n);
```

After creating `outlierIndices`, it gets passed into `.data()`, with `Number` as a some funky second arg.

```
  // Update outliers.
  var outlier = g.selectAll("circle.outlier")
      .data(outlierIndices, Number);

  outlier.enter().insert("circle", "text")
      .attr("class", "outlier")
      .attr("r", 5)
      .attr("cx", width / 2)
      .attr("cy", function(i) { return x0(d[i]); })
      .style("opacity", 1e-6)
    .transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("cy", function(i) { return x1(d[i]); })
      .style("opacity", 1);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After poking around the [box plot example](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4061502) you gave, I think the best solution is to modify `d3.box` in that code...

Instead of attempting to mimic the y scale, I think you should expose the y scale used in `d3.box` *NOTE: internally to `d3.box`, the "Y" scale is named `x1()` despite being a vertical scale*.

**(1) add a function `box.x1()` that we'll call to apply the scaling**

```
box.x1 = function(x) {
    if (!arguments.length) return x1;
    return x1(x);
  };

// Left this here to show where box.x1 is being added
box.width = function(x) {
    if (!arguments.length) return width;
    width = x;
    return box;
  };
```

**(2) Since we're calling `x1` in the above `box.x1` function it needs to be available from the scope of d3.box (not just in the secondary box(g){} function that does all the d3 stuff)**

Add x1 in with the other box variables:

```
var width = 1,
    height = 1,
    duration = 0,
    domain = null,
    value = Number,
    whiskers = boxWhiskers,
    quartiles = boxQuartiles,
    tickFormat = null;
    x1 = null;
```

No need to create x1 as a variable later when you define the scale, so you can lose the `var` preceding `x1 =...`

```
x1 = d3.scale.linear()
      .domain(domain && domain.call(this, d, i) || [min, max])
      .range([height, 0]);
```

Now when x1 is set, you'll be able to call it with box.x1()

**To actually implement this, I just added the following in index.html:**

```
d3.selectAll(".box")
    .data([800]) //I just used a hardcoded value for simplicity
        .append("circle")
        .attr("cx", chart.width()/2+margin.left)
        .attr("cy", function(d){return chart.x1(d);}) // using same scale that was used to draw the box plot.
        .attr("r", 5)
```

And the individual data point shows up where it's supposed to...

[image]

With the scale exposed in the form of box.x1 (or in this case chart.x1), I think it should be pretty simple to add points and have them placed where you want them.

Comment: Thanks Steve.  Just want to add that I ended up replacing the `domain` of `x1` with `.domain(d3.extent(d))` to ensure when the data updates, it will re-scale the chart.